# Métodos de Ordenação em C

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um trabalho com três modos de ordenação em C e eu escolhi um sistema de estacionamento só com o modelo e a marca do carro porém estou travada na hora de criar a ordenação. Quero pegar as informações do cadastro e com elas fazer a ordenação.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

char cadastroCarro () {

    char modeloCarro[20];
    char marcaCarro[20];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf ("Modelo Carro: ");
        scanf ("%s", &modeloCarro[i]);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("MarcaCarro: ");
        scanf ("%s", &MarcaCarro[k]);
        printf ("\n");
    }

}


main () {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int menu, menuOrdenacao;

    printf ("Sistema de Estacionamento");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("[1] Cadastro");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("[2] Modo de Ordenação");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("[3] Sair");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Escolha uma das opções:");
    scanf ("%d", &menu);
    printf ("\n");

    if (menu == 1) {
        cadastroCarro();
    }

    if (menu == 2) {
        printf ("Modo de Ordenação");
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("[1] Bubble Sort");
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("[2] Selection Sort");
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("[3] Quick Sort");
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Escolha um modo:");
        scanf ("%d", &menuOrdenacao);

        if (menuOrdenacao == 1) {
            // Bubble Sort
        }

        if (menuOrdenacao == 2) {
            // Selection Sort
        }

        if (menuOrdenacao == 3) {
            //QuickSort
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Em primeiro lugar suas variáveis modeloCarro e marcaCarro precisam ser arrays de strings e não um string único. Pesquise na internet pelos métodos de ordenação e aplique a seu problema. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o